# How to create a fast loading wrapping ListBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, virtualization

I've made a nice little three-item wide list of tiles that work as switches. It looks something like this:

[image: tile switcher]

Looking good huh? Well, I have about 130 of these tiles in a vertically scrolling list, and it takes ages to load. According to the performance analysis tool, each element takes about 18ms to render - which gives me about a 2.3 second rendering time. On the device, it's often twice that time. This wouldn't really be a crisis, but the UI is totally black and unresponsive up until these elements have been drawn.

After some research online, I realized this is because the `WrapPanel` control from the toolkit doesn't virtualize its items - thus making the `GPU` render all objects at once (using up a lot of memory in the process).

Now, are there any ways to make this go faster?

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ChannelsListBox" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,40,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="ChannelTile" Margin="6,6,6,6" Tap="ChannelTile_Tap">
                <!-- context menu code removed -->
                <Rectangle Width="136" Height="136" Fill="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" />    
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The `ListBox`'s ItemsSource is set in the codebehind - if you wondered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you populate the listbox asynchronously from another thread, you can avoid the unresponsive UI.

EDITED2:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        /* In the xaml code:
           <ListBox x:Name="ChannelsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfTestClasses}" ...
        */

        var vm = new MainPageViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;

        vm.StartLoadingDataAsync(10000);
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> ListOfTestClasses { get; set; }
    private BackgroundWorker workerThread;
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ListOfTestClasses = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.Argument; i++)
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    ListOfTestClasses.Add(new TestClass { Text = "Element " + (i + 1) });
                });

                Thread.Sleep(150);
            }
        });
    }

    public void StartLoadingDataAsync(int numberOfElements)
    {
        workerThread.RunWorkerAsync(numberOfElements);   
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to use some simplier "container" insted of the Grid (for example, Canvas).
And a shitty solution can be for example, waiting some time before adding the next element. In this case the whole rendering takes more time, but the UI won't be unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks @laszlokiss88 - this actually worked quite well. I still have some problems with the threads messing up the order and what not, but with a bit of luck, I'll make it work. Thanks for spending time on writing some example code for me as well :-)

Comment: is there a reason Thread.Sleep is set exactly to 150 ms? Anything lower (like 50 or 100) results in each element being shown several times.

Comment: No, it's just a "random" number. You should define this according your rendering time.

Comment: why does it keep on adding the same item several times though? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: oh my god, can't believe I didn't see this before. Thanks so much. +1

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas which might be helpful:

1. Find or implement a virtualizing WrapPanel. It's the most appropriate solution, but I don't think I've seen a solid implementation of one yet. But for this purpose, maybe you don't need perfection and can get away with something someone else has already written.
2. Use a parent virtualizing vertical StackPanel containing horizontal StackPanel children. To do this, you'd need to re-shape your single sequence of data into a shorter sequence of 3-item entries. However, that may not be too hard and should give you most of the benefits of the ideal solution.
3. Consider implementing "lazy" containers like I did for DeferredLoadListBox. The basic idea is to delay rendering containers until they show up on screen. I have more info and example code here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/08/never-do-today-what-you-can-put-off-till-tomorrow-deferredloadlistbox-and-stackpanel-help-windows-phone-7-lists-scroll-smoothly-and-consistently.aspx

Comment: All great ideas David - I've looked into creating a virtualizing WrapPanel, but since I'm on a schedule, getting into that might be a bit overkill. A nice sideproject idea for later, though. The vertical / horizontal StackPanel combo probably won't work too well for me, since I need to be able to drag these suckers around later on. A "lazy" implementation, however, might be what I'll do. Thanks for your thougths on the subject.